# Find parameter distribution how i know any initial value i must put?

Tags: parameters

```
FindMaximum::eit: The algorithm does not 
converge to the tolerance of _4.806217383937354`*^-6_ in _500_ iterations
```

[image: any initial value I must put in FindParameterDistributio]

Comment: You make it difficult for anyone to help.  Please edit your question to include necessary information with text and code rather than a very dark and unreadable image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data and probability distribution from [a previous question of yours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241725/plot-statistics-for-chen-weibull), the following works fine on *Mathematica* 12.2 (Windows 10):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", Divide[1 - Exp[λ (1 - Exp[(1 - Exp[-(x/α)^γ])^β])], 
    1 - Exp[λ - λ Exp[1]]]}, {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {λ > 0, β > 0, α > 0, γ > 0}]

data = {70, 90, 96, 97, 99, 103, 104, 104, 105, 107, 108, 108, 108, 
   109, 109, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 114, 116, 119, 120, 120, 120, 
   121, 121, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 
   130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 133, 134, 134, 
   134, 134, 136, 136, 137, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 141, 141, 142, 
   142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 144, 144, 145, 146, 148, 148, 
   149, 151, 151, 152, 155, 156, 155, 156, 157, 157, 157, 157, 158, 
   159, 162, 163, 163, 164, 166, 166, 168, 170, 174, 201, 212};

mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist, {{λ, 47}, {β, 1.5}, {α, 20}, {γ, -4}}]
(* {λ -> 2.91285, β -> 3.45368, α -> 133.646, γ -> 3.37814} *)

Show[Histogram[data, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[dist /. mle, x], {x, Min[data], Max[data]}]]
```

[image: Histogram and distribution fit]

So you might want to try starting values closer to the maximum likelihood estimates or increase the maximum number of iterations (say, `MaxIterations->5000`).

Comment: thanks you JimB